# How to disable "Save As" option in print dialog in PHP and Javascript web application. The dialog should appear if printer is connected no downloading

Tags: javascript, printing, web-applications, dialog, save-as

I have this issue at hand. Am doing a web system with PHP CodeIgniter for a publisher organization.
Everything is fully implemented apart from Printing.
**Now the system is supposed to allow only printing of the materials.** No downloading,
That means the print dialog should not contain the **"save as"** option. **Neither should it pop up if the printer is not connected.**
Any idea on how to achieve this is very much welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using `onbeforeprinting` but I have not achieved the functionality.
`JsPrintManager` works with few browsers hence implementation has limitations